# KVM with VirtioFS on host, Windows Server guest, VirtioFS access denied

Tags: kvm-virtualization, qemu, virtio

I have some successful setups of Linux guests under KVM with [VirtioFS](https://virtio-fs.gitlab.io/), even able to boot from theese folders without any "classical" drive images or dedicated partitions.

Now, I have a need run a Windows Server guest, and share files from it with the host. I've read that VirtioFS is supported on Windows guests, so I've installed WinFSP (as per [this manual](https://virtio-fs.gitlab.io/howto-windows.html)), [theese drivers](https://github.com/virtio-win/virtio-win-pkg-scripts/blob/master/README.md) (which have support for VirtioFS), the Z: drive even appeared... But that's all. When attempting to access it - I just get an "Access Denied" error and no access to the underlying VirtioFS filesystem.

[image: Screenshot of the problem]

Things I've tried:

1. chmoding 777 the target folder - no changes
2. Fiddling around with virtiofsd command line arguments - no changes
3. Trying to run the virtiofs.exe on the guest manually - It just crashes on attempting to access the Z: drive for no apparent reason (although seems to work fine when running as an autostartable service)
4. Trying both virtiofsd host demons - [rust](https://gitlab.com/virtio-fs/virtiofsd-rs) one and C one. The C one tends to crash for weird reasons...

I'm a bit of at loss about what to do now. The same setup (with the rust demon) works just fine with Linux.

What am I doing wrong?

UPD: for some reason, each and every request on the guest (while running `virtiofs.exe -d -1 -D -` directly) ends up with an error `BytesReturned != hdr->len, Bytes returned: 0, Expected: xxx`.

Answer (score 1):

I've had same issue and found this solution. Hope it helps.

https://github.com/virtio-win/kvm-guest-drivers-windows/issues/760#issuecomment-1103590985